# Video capture on MacOS

Tags: macos, qt, qt4, video-capture

I'm wrtiting a C++ application with Trolltech QT Library and I need to capture video stream from a camera and some medical instrumentations.

What kind of hardware can I use to do this? I've tried with OpenCV but it doesn't recognize my EyeTV 250.

Can I use Pinnacle Video capture for Mac?

thanks, 
Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that Qt delegates to QuickTime for media on OS X. I'd therefore expect that any hardware [supported](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTKitCaptureProgrammingGuide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004574-CH3-DontLinkElementID_19) by QuickTime is in play. If you're willing to be locked to OS X, using the native API will likely be much easier. QTKit, the Objective-C API for QuickTime is new with Leopard (OS X 10.5) and is very good. You'll likely want to start with [QTKit's Capture API](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTKitCaptureProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). Since you're working with C++, you'll also want to learn about [Objective-C++](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH10-SW1) for building the connection between QTKit and your code.

Comment: Thanks Barry. I try with QTKit, but if possible I prefer to use OpenCV to capture video because I need to port the QTApplication on Windows.

Comment: It looks like OpenCV supports at least some hardware on OS X: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/#Welcome.2BAC8-OS.MacOSXVersion

Comment: Furthermore, OpenCV should now support any DCam/IIDC on OS X via libdc1394. See http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port.

Comment: The problem is that i don't know what kind of hardware i need to connect my camera to my mac. I've tried with Elgato EYETV250 but openCV and avcap-0.1.6 libs but neither of them recognize the camera.

Answer (score 0):

Try openCV, there is a good project here : http://code.google.com/p/opencv-cocoa/ there are c++ class.